# EC2 instance gives ssh connection time out error after installing SSL certificate

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, ssh

I am using an Amazon EC2 instance for the last 2 months but today I am unable to connect to it. Earlier I was connecting using ssh and the service is still running (http://ec2-13-233-199-251.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com).

Last night I tried to add an SSL certifcate from Let's Encrypt using this blog: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-apache-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04

After that, when I try to connect to the EC2 instance using ssh as:

```
ssh -i "majorPillar.pem" ubuntu@ec2-13-233-199-251.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

I am getting connection time out error.

I checked my security group and port 22 is open and other inbound and outbound rules are correct. How can I connect to my instance now?

Comment: Double-check that your instance is still using the same IP address.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Yes sir it is still using the same IP address

Comment: Have you tried to reboot ec2 instance from aws console?

Comment: done. Still same result

Answer (score -1):

the port 22 in your server does not respond, 443 port refuses connections.

Double check your configuration in aws console:
inbound traffic configuration on port 22, ensure *your ip address* has access to that port.
For example:

```
nc -zv 13.233.199.251 22
```

The https certificate install should not have side-effects on ssh config.
Anyway, check `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` configuration file too and ensure ssh port is the one you want (22?)

```
sudo grep Port /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Comment: I set port 22 to allow any and my security group work for other instance. I also think that it is due to https certificate but what can I do without connecting to my server.

Comment: @Evhz I also have similar issue. Where to run this command sudo grep Port /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Comment: if you cannot ssh into your instance, there's nothing else you can do. Have a look at [this](https://vimalpaliwal.com/blog/2018/12/c98ebbc626/regain-access-to-aws-ec2-instance-in-case-you-lost-private-key.html) source. There are other cloud services offering their own ssh recovery backdoors like linode.